# How can I reset the state in child component when using useContext?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, frontend

I have removed some useless code and posted my code here.
When I first click on the button in DealWithHands, everything goes smoothly. However, when I click the button in DealWithHands again, the table in Analysis still keep its calculation result before and continue the calculation based on the previous result. This is not expected. How could I fix this.

I think there are two ways to do this.

1. Clicking the button will first unmount the child component, then mount it again. But I don't know how to do it and it may take time.
2. Parent component controls the state in child component. I don't think this is a good way because the state in child component has no relationship with parent component.

If you want the real code, you can visit https://github.com/S-N-O-R-L-A-X/Bridge-Tools.

```
import { useState, ChangeEvent, useMemo } from "react";

import "./index.css";
import ShowResults from "../Show/ShowResults";

function deal() {
    /* get boards */
}

export default function DealWithHands() {
    const [board_size, setBoard_size] = useState<number>(1);
    const [boards, setBoards] = useState<any[][]>([]);

    function handleSize(e: ChangeEvent) {
        setBoard_size(Number((e.target as HTMLInputElement).value));
    }

    function handleClick() {
        setBoards(deal(Number(board_size)));
    }

    return (
        <>
            <div className="deal-setting">
                <input value={board_size} onChange={handleSize} placeholder="input your number here"></input>
                <button onClick={handleClick}>Get new boards</button>
            </div>
            {useMemo(() => <ShowResults all_boards={boards.map((x) => { return { board: x } })} />
                , [boards])}
        </>
    )
}
```

```
import React, { createContext } from "react";
import ShowAllBoards from "../../Components/ShowAllBoards/ShowAllBoards";
import Hand from "../Deal/Hand";
import Analysis from "../Analysis/Analysis";

export interface CompleteBoard {
    board: Hand[];
    ddtricks?: (string | number)[][] | string;
}

interface ShowResultsProps {
    all_boards: CompleteBoard[];
}

interface ShowResultsContextProps {
    all_boards: CompleteBoard[];
}

export const ShowResultsContext = createContext<ShowResultsContextProps>({ all_boards: []});

function ShowResults(props: ShowResultsProps) {
    const { all_boards, ...rest } = props;
    return (
        <ShowResultsContext.Provider value={{ all_boards }}>
            <Analysis />
            <ShowAllBoards {...rest} />
        </ShowResultsContext.Provider>
    )
}

export default React.memo(ShowResults);
```

```
import React, { useContext,  useMemo, useState } from "react";
import ShowTricks from "../../Components/PlayBoard/ShowTricks";
import { analyzeOffline } from "../../Utils/utils";
import { ShowResultsContext } from "../Show/ShowResults";
import "./analysis.css"

function MatrixAdd(a: number[][], b: (string | number)[][]) {
  const ret: number[][] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    ret[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < a[0].length; ++j) {
      ret[i][j] = a[i][j] + Number(b[i][j]);
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

function MatrixDivide(a: number[][], b: number) {
  const ret: number[][] = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
    ret[i] = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < a[0].length; ++j) {
      ret[i][j] = a[i][j] / b;
    }
  }
  return ret;
}

function Analysis() {
  const [table, setTable] = useState(new Array(4).fill(0).map(() => new Array(5).fill(0)));
  const context = useContext(ShowResultsContext);
  const { all_boards } = context;
  useMemo(() => {
    async function countTricks() {
      let tmp: number[][] = [];
      table.forEach((row) => {
        tmp.push([...row]);
      })
      for (const board of all_boards) {
        if (!board.ddtricks) {
          board.ddtricks = await analyzeOffline(board.board);
        }
        tmp = MatrixAdd(tmp, board.ddtricks as (string | number)[][]);
      }
      return Promise.resolve(tmp);
    }
    countTricks().then((res) => {
      if (all_boards.length > 0) {
        setTable(MatrixDivide(res, all_boards.length));
      }
    })
  }, [all_boards])

  return (
    <fieldset className="showStatistics">
      <legend>The average tricks:</legend>
      <ShowTricks ddtricks={table} />
    </fieldset>
  )
}

export default Analysis;
```

Answer (score 0):

when i think about mounting and unmounting a component it usually come to my mind the useEffect from my experience it helped me quite some times u can give it a try and give it a dependency ofc, i hope it helps you good luck.

Comment: I have tried useEffect in Analysis but it does not work. So I tried useMemo.